# "FROM keyword not found where expected" (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have the following query which gives me the error in the title. I have no idea why it's giving me the error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW AUSTRALIANMEDALTALLY
AS
SELECT concat(SG_HOSTCITY, SG_YEAR) as 'ioc_game',
SUM(p.part_gold) as 'gold_medals',
SUM(p.part_silver) as 'silver_medals',
SUM(p.part_bronze) as 'bronze_medals'
FROM GAMES.SUMMERGAMES, GAMES.PARTICIPATION
WHERE COUNTRY_ISOCODE = AUS
GROUP BY COUNTRY_ISOCODE;
```

Any idea why I'm getting the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As well as `AUS` needing to to be quoted as `'AUS'`, your aliases either need to be double-quoted:

```
SELECT concat(SG_HOSTCITY, SG_YEAR) as "ioc_game",
```

which makes them case-sensitive, or not quoted at all:

```
SELECT concat(SG_HOSTCITY, SG_YEAR) as ioc_game,
```

And the same for the other aliases.

You also refer to a `p` as a table alias but you don't define that - presumably that's for `participants` - and you aren't defining how the tables are related, so you're doing a cross-join. Seems like you probably have the country in both tables, too, so you need to prefix the references with the table alias.

And you're grouping by a column that isn't in the select-list, which will cause its own error; you need to group by any columns you aren't aggregating.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW AUSTRALIANMEDALTALLY
AS
SELECT concat(s.SG_HOSTCITY, s.SG_YEAR) as ioc_game,
SUM(p.part_gold) as gold_medals,
SUM(p.part_silver) as silver_medals,
SUM(p.part_bronze) as bronze_medals
FROM GAMES.SUMMERGAMES s
JOIN GAMES.PARTICIPATION p
ON p.gamesno = s.gamesno
WHERE p.COUNTRY_ISOCODE = 'AUS'
GROUP BY s.SG_HOSTCITY, s.SG_YEAR;
```

Comment: I tried doing that, and i get an error saying "column ambiguously defined". I double quoted my aliases and single quoted AUS.

Comment: Is `country_isocode` in both tables? You should specify which table each column is from to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Yes it is, and I tried doing so still same error. How do I comment a code on this site?

Comment: @Mr10k - you can't get that error if every column is prefixed with its table alias. Maybe you only changed one of the references? Your grouping was wrong too though.

Comment: I just changed the 's' identified to 'sg' and it worked perfectly.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE COUNTRY_ISOCODE = AUS
```

change to

```
WHERE COUNTRY_ISOCODE = 'AUS'
```

Comment: try `as bronze_medals` not `as 'bronze_medals'` ( all of the as statements )

Comment: @Mr10k can you paste the last sql query of yours

Comment: My last query is too long to paste as a comment, but as I've ended my last query with a ';' it shouldn't affect the query I'm writing now?